# how to switch back to previous window in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I want to go back to previous page but I cant go back. please help me.I used this code

```
driver.switchto().primary();

driver.switchtodefault();

driver.switchtoFrame("Frame_Main");
```

Answer (score 4):

To move back from the current window to previous window, you can use the following commands,

```
driver.getUIWindowLocator().switchToFirstWindow();
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().firstWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get current window
String mainWindowHandle = webDriver.getWindowHandles().iterator().next();
// do what you want in other window
// ...
// switch back
webDriver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In C# that would be:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);
```

Maybe there's something similar in whatever you are using (Java?)!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use the following in order to move between iterators of all window handles:

```
  Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
  for (String handle : allWindowHandles) {
            driver.switchTo().window(allWindowHandles.iterator().next());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Get the handle of the current window
    String currentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

    // Get the handles of all open windows
    Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    // Remove the handle of the current window from the set of handles
    windowHandles.remove(currentWindowHandle);

    // Switch to the new window
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles.iterator().next());
    Thread.sleep(10000);//You can add explicit wait too


    //Switch to previous window
    driver.switchTo().window(currentWindowHandle);
```